# Laravel 5.3 Eager Loading Selected Fields

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this code:

```
 $products = \App\Product::whereIn('id', $arrayKeys)
                ->with('photo')
                ->get();
```

And the result is:
[image]

If I use select code like this one:

```
 $products = \App\Product::whereIn('id', $arrayKeys)
                ->select(['desc'])
                ->with('photo')
                ->get();
```

[image]

I can't see the photo. Is there a way to it? So that I can get the selected fields as well as the photo relationship.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the `id` too? `->select(['id', 'desc'])`?

Comment: It's definitelly problem with `id`. Try it again. as @Doom5 said. Maybe like this: `->select('id', 'desc')`